# Using eval() to check if constant isset

Tags: php, eval, constants

I am trying to check defined variables based on passing a single portion of the variable. (The rest of the variable is static and all other portions of it are the same), so I made a test to find out if this is possible.

It does not work, but perhaps I am doing something small that is easily fixed.

```
define('TEST', 'works');
$test = 't';

echo TES . strtoupper($test);
echo eval('TES . strtoupper('.$test.');');
echo eval('TES . strtoupper(\'$test\');');

echo eval('TES' . strtoupper($test) . ';');
```

Comment: why don't you just use `defined`?

Comment: `echo eval('echo constant("TEST");');` why are you using `eval`?

Comment: So where are we with the question? Did any of the answers below answered your question/ solved your problem ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work for you:

Just use [`constant()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.constant.php) to build the constant name as string and then pass it to the function.

```
echo constant("TES". strtoupper($test));
```

output:

```
works
```

Comment: Use defined, otherwise you'll get warning. http://php.net/manual/en/function.defined.php

Comment: Great job, thank you.  Now I can be very cleaver in a class I was working on.

Comment: No. Not when using eval to check if global variables exist.

Answer (score 5):

If you want to check if a constant is defined, simply use [defined()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.defined.php)

```
<?php
if (defined('TEST')) {
    echo TEST;
}
?>
```

Comment: This does not answer the question. It does not echo the value of test.

Comment: <?=defined('TEST') ? TEST : '';=>

Answer (score 0):

`'TEST'` **is not** a global variable. It is a [constant](http://php.net/manual/en/language.constants.php). The constants have global scope, they can be accessed from any context (given you know the name of the constant you want to use). There is no need to do any hack using `eval()`.

If you generate the name of the constant on runtime for some reason, you can use the PHP function [`defined()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.defined.php) to check if there is a constant already defined having that name and, if the constant exists, you can get its value using the function [`constant()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.constant.php)

Like this:

```
define('TEST', 'works');
$test = 't';

echo 'TES'.strtoupper($test);

// Compute the constant's name
$name = 'TES'.strtoupper($test);
// Check if the constant exists and get its value
if (defined($name)) {
    echo("The constant '".$name."' is already defined.\n");
    echo("It's value is: ".constant($name)."\n");
}
```

Comment: I did not add the global tag, some other guy did.

Comment: @Iscariot I took care of it and did a rollback, since the other guy changed the intention of  your code.

Comment: yeah, I love how people change your question so that their answer is correct..  That Uni guy I am 100% sure if upvoting himself with ult accounts.  It was at +4 immediately.

Comment: @Iscariot With: *That Uni guy* I'm going to assume, that you mean Uri Goren; Just take a simple principle and don't accuse someone unless you can proof it.